# Do you say "don't slap in the pee to make it be smeared all over the floor and splash it into my face"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [slap](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/slap) 4 [intransitive always + adverb/preposition] to hit a surface
>   with a lot of force, making a loud sharp sound
>
> slap against
>
> Small waves slapped against the side of the boat.

[image]

Today, my son peed his shorts on my chair, then he slapped **on / in** the pee (**not sure "on" or "in"**), which made the pee be smeared all over my room & sometimes splashed it into my face (**not sure "sometimes" is the right word**:

"sometimes" is normally used for a longer period, eg, I sometimes go shopping. But in this specific situation, the period that my son did it lasted about 3 minutes and within that 3 minutes, sometimes (**2 or 3 times**) the pee splashed into my face).

Do you say "**don't slap in the pee to make it be smeared all over the floor and splash it into my face**"?

Comment: I think in those circumstances most people would say simply "Don't do that!" or "Stop that!". But _splashed over the floor_ describes the situation better, because _smeared_ implies that the substance was rubbed over a surface.

Comment: @KateBunting, sometimes he moved his hand back and forward in the pee and made it all over the floor